# I have python 3.7.4 installed but I am unable to install dolfin package

Tags: python, pip

I have `python 3.7.4` installed on my computer in windows platform. I can not install `dolfin` package

```
pip install dolfin
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Dolfin (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for Dolfin

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply install [dolfin](https://pypi.org/project/DOLFIN/) package using [pip](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/dolfin/issues/515/installation-from-pip-in-virtualenv-fails).

Check this official [doc](https://fenicsproject.org/docs/dolfin/dev/python/installation.html) for detailed guide.

After installation you need to install these python dependencies.

- pybind11 *(https://github.com/pybind/pybind11)*
- NumPy *(http://www.numpy.org)*
- ply *(https://github.com/dabeaz/ply)*

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [issue #515](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/dolfin/issues/515/installation-from-pip-in-virtualenv-fails), `pip install dolfin` is not possible.

You may want to check [general documentation](https://fenicsproject.org/download/) or [code documentation](https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/dev/python/installation.html) for the installation guide.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct. It's currently (still) not possible to install dolfin via pip (as of 11/2021).

I want to add to the other answers, that it is also possible to install dolfin conveniently via the conda package manager: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/fenics-dolfin

1. If you don't have the `conda` command, install [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/linux/) or [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Miniconda is enough, since you only need the `conda` command and packages dependencies will be installed automatically by `conda`.
   *Note: After the installation, I needed to execute `source ~/.profile` to
   activate the default virtualenv in which `conda` is accessible.*
2. Execute `conda install -c conda-forge fenics-dolfin` to install `dolfin`.

I don't like to install conda system-wide for this, but this way it's possible to install `dolfin` without building anything from source yourself. (I assume you are looking for a quick and easy way to install dolfin, since you did not ask a specific question.)